# Create Oracle Users in a loop

Tags: oracle, for-loop, oracle11g

I am trying to create oracle users and grant connection using a loop. This is what I have so far.

I get an error `Encountered the symbol "USERID"`. I assume I need to escape the `userid` somehow.

```
BEGIN
  FOR USERNAME IN (SELECT USERID FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME WHERE USERID NOT IN(SELECT NAME FROM USER$))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || USERNAME || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' USERNAME;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CONNECT TO ' || USERNAME;                                  
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Any help to fix the statement would be appreciated.

Edit: Change cursor name for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the string concatenation operator `||` after the "IDENTIFIED BY" string and before the second `USERID`.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || USERID || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || USERID;
```

You also appear to want to refer to the `USERID` column in the `USERNAME` cursor.  Assuming that is the case, you'd need to use the syntax `USERNAME.USERID`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || USERNAME.USERID || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || USERNAME.USERID;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CONNECT TO ' || USERNAME.USERID;
```

Comment: That fixed the error. Now I get this error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'`. Any insights?

Comment: @theking963 - Updated.  I didn't notice that you were trying to use the `USERID` column from the `USERID` cursor.

Comment: Poor choice or variable name...Thanks. I will accept it in a few mins when it will allow me to.

Comment: Regardless of the variable name i needed `varname.userid`. For clarity's sake for other people I am going to change the cursor name in the question. Please modify the answer variable name. And I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

you can not create user with the numeric value like 1,2,3,4.... in the loop.

if you want to can concate with the string value like abc1,abc2,abc3. abc is default value and 1,2,3 count in a loop..

```
declare
user varchar(10);
id number(10);
pwd varchar(10);

begin
for id in 1..3
loop
user:='abc';
pswd:='abcd';--password
user=user||id;--concate user+numeric value here.
execute immediate'create user'||user||'identifid by '||pswd;
execute immediate'grant connect to'||user;
execute immediate'grant resource to'||user;
end loop;
end;
```